# Xcode - run on ios device doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I'm creating an app, and I've signed up for everything to have the app run on my iPad and it does most of the time. But every so often when I go to select my iPad in the "run on" drop down box it just says "ios device".

It can't seem to find my device.

This happens from time to time, and next time I try, it might work fine.

Any ideas why it might not always find the device?

Thanks

Comment: check your os version in build settings -- > Deployment target. Change it to proper version

Comment: thanks where exactly is that I can't seem to find it

Comment: check Ramani's answer

Comment: that isnt the correct answer. I want it to work on my own device. Sometimes it appears in the drop down list and sometimes it doesn't. I was asking does anyone know how I can get it to appear

Comment: if you change the version it will automatially appear

Comment: The simulator doesn't run on your iPad - it runs on your development host.

Comment: I just want to clear up something you seem to be mistaking. You can either run in the Simulator, or on a Device - but the Simulator never runs on a Device. The Simulator, as its name suggest simulates the iOS Device on your Mac enabling you to run an app without having to have a physical device connected. When you run your app on a physical device there is no simulation - the app is running natively on the device.

Comment: it might be foolish to say, but is your usb connecting cable properly connected to your device ?

Comment: Maybe the cable is defect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using xcode 5.1 then it will give you some errors like this.
You just **force Quit** the xcode from **Activity Monitor** and then again reopen the project. Now you can not found this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can get your device by the following steps.

Go to **Project Navigator Panel**.

Select your **Project**

navigate to **general** tab.

Into **Deployment info** Select **Deployment target** as per device OS.

Now you find your device in the drop down list.

[image]

Comment: think you have misunderstood the question. I want the simulator to run on my own iPad, I can get it to run the simulator of an iPad on the laptop, but I want it to run on my own device. For some reason every so often it doesn't appear in the drop down selection any ideas?

Comment: where you want to run the app in simulator or in device..?